# Using a Timer to break a loop

Tags: java, loops, timer

I am trying to build a timeout for a call/response ping. This is to determine which CommPort to use in an auto-connect sequence. When I send the `CALL_SIGNAL` byte[], I expect to get "FU" in reply. This is how I will determine which is my device. The SSCCE is below (sorry for the length, but this *is* the shortened version)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.CommPort;
import javax.comm.PortInUseException;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;

public class PingTest {
    public static final long PING_TIMEOUT = 1000; // in millis
    public static final byte[] CALL_SIGNAL = {70, 68, 73, 68};

    public boolean ping(CommPortIdentifier cpi)  {
        System.out.println("Pinging " + cpi.getName());
        CommPort port = null;
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;

        //Initialization test
        try {
            port = cpi.open("pingTest", 50);
            input = port.getInputStream();
            output = port.getOutputStream();
        } catch (PortInUseException ex) {
            if (cpi.getCurrentOwner().startsWith("pingTest")) {
                System.out.println("Port already owned by this application.");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
            port.close();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Failed initialization test.");
            System.err.println(ex);
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("Passed initialization test."); 

        //Call and response test
        final Stop stop = new Stop();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Stop timer triggered.");
                stop.shouldStop = true;
            }
        }, PING_TIMEOUT);
        try {
            System.out.println("Writing...");
            output.write(CALL_SIGNAL);
            System.out.println("Reading...");
            boolean waitForF = true;
            while (!stop.shouldStop && !stop.didPass) {
                if (waitForF) {
                    if ((byte) 'F' == input.read()) {
                        waitForF = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println('F');
                    if ((byte) 'U' == input.read()) {
                        System.out.println('U');
                        stop.didPass = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println();
                        waitForF = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed I/O test.");
            return false;
        } finally {
            port.close();
        }

        if (stop.didPass) {
            System.out.println("Successful ping.");
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("Failed call and response test.");
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PingTest pinger = new PingTest();
        Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        boolean trigger = true;
        String name = null;
        while (trigger && ports.hasMoreElements) {
            CommPortIdentifier cpi = ports.nextElement();
            name = cpi.getName();
            trigger = !ping(cpi);
        }
        if (trigger) {
            System.out.println("Found it. It is " + name);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}

class Stop {
    boolean shouldStop = false;
    boolean didPass = false;
}
```

My output is:

```
Pinging COM1
Passed initialization test.
Writing...
Reading...
Stop timer triggered.
```

And then the application freezes. Is there a problem with trying to stop the while loop with a `Timer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reads are blocking. You need to use [Timeouts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/CommPort.html#enableReceiveTimeout%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing shared state (the `shouldStop` and `didPass` variables) from different threads concurrently without any synchronization. Every access should be synchronized if you want to make sure to read what the other thread wrote.

So, either add methods to get and set these variables, and make those methods synchronized, or, if each variable represents an distinct information from the other and they can be written and read independantly, make those variables volatile.

A third way (which is only valid under the same conditions as the volatile solution) is to use AtomicBoolean variables instead of boolean variables.